# mathematica: evaluation order in numerical integration

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

Hi i have a problem concerning a numerical integration in mathematica. Here is my test function

```
Table[NIntegrate[
Boole[Sqrt[1 - cosk^2]*Sqrt[1 - cosk2^2] > Abs[a - cosk*cosk2]]/
Sqrt[(1 - cosk^2)*(1 - cosk2^2) - (a - cosk*cosk2)^2],
{cosk, -1,1}, {cosk2, -1, 1}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"], {a, -.9, .9, .1}]
```

The integration yields complex values although due to the boolean function in the integrand the argument in the sqrt should be always positive and hence only result in real values. Is it possible to first evaluate the boole function and only if it is true then start to numerically integrate?

If i calculate the same integral using a monte carlo integration strategy

```
Table[NIntegrate[
Boole[Sqrt[1 - cosk^2]*Sqrt[1 - cosk2^2] > Abs[a - cosk*cosk2]]/
Sqrt[(1 - cosk^2)*(1 - cosk2^2) - (a - cosk*cosk2)^2], {cosk, -1, 
1}, {cosk2, -1, 1}, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^8, 
"SymbolicProcessing" -> None}], {a, -.9, .9, .1}]
```

how can I find out if it sums up a lot of zeroes due to the boolean function? I think the evaluation can save a lot of computation time if it first evaluates the boolean function for each sample point of the monte carlo grid. If i replace "MonteCarlo" by "AdaptiveMonteCarlo" the result goes totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you convert to a true guard? (The `Boole` form may be too clever by half (Mathematica might not treat false --> 0 as a real guard).)

```
Table[NIntegrate[
If[Sqrt[1 - cosk^2]*Sqrt[1 - cosk2^2] > Abs[a - cosk*cosk2],
1/Sqrt[(1 - cosk^2)*(1 - cosk2^2) - (a - cosk*cosk2)^2], 0],
{cosk, -1,1}, {cosk2, -1, 1}], {a, -.9, .9, .1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to use `EvaluationMonitor` to learn what the sampling methods do:

```
out = Reap[With[{a = -.9},
   NIntegrate[
    v = Boole[
       Sqrt[1 - cosk^2]*Sqrt[1 - cosk2^2] > Abs[a - cosk*cosk2]]/
      Sqrt[(1 - cosk^2)*(1 - cosk2^2) - (a - 
           cosk*cosk2)^2], {cosk, -1, 1}, {cosk2, -1, 1}, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{cosk, cosk2, v}]]]]
```

Note `LocalAdaptive` is very slow, but is likely the most accurate purely numerical result:

```
     Graphics@Point[out[[2, 1]][[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

[image]

here is global adaptive.

[image]

MonteCarlo just samples everywhere without regard to the integrand value.

Your best bet probably is to use global adaptive and set `MinRecursion`. Satisfy yourself the imaginary parts are negligible and take the real part of the result.
Of course it would be far better to analytically solve for your integration limits and eliminate the `Boole` all together.